# query to return null values when none exist in one table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I need to list out 6 medical offices in one column, and the patient's full name in the other.  If the patient has never visited that office before, then a NULL should appear.

- The table structures are simple with MedicalOffice having an ID,
  Name, and a few miscellaneous columns.
- MedicalProcedure has the
  officeID, patientID, patient's full name, and some miscellaneous
  columns.

There is only one ID per office in the MedicalOffice table, but MedicalProcedure can have many officeIDs per patient and even the same officeID for the same patient more than once.

Following some answers I found here on SO, I tried a left outer join:

```
select  m.Name, p.FullName
from MedicalOffice m
left outer join MedicalProcedure p ON  m.ID = p.officeID
where m.ID IN   (1,2,3,4,5,6)
AND p.patientID = 111
GROUP BY m.Name,  p.patientID
ORDER BY m.Name
```

Then a left join:

```
select  m.Name, p.FullName
from MedicalOffice m
left  join MedicalProcedure p ON  m.ID = p.officeID
where m.ID IN   (1,2,3,4,5,6)
AND p.patientID = 111
GROUP BY m.Name,  p.patientID
ORDER BY m.Name
```

but I only get the offices where a record exists in the MedicalProcedure table like this:

```
    Name       |    FullName
----------------------------------
Office 1         Smith, John
Office 2         Smith, John 
Office 4         Smith, John
```

But, if patientID 111 had 3 records in the MedicalProcedure table for Offices 1,2, and 4, the results should look like this:

```
Name       |    FullName
----------------------------------
Office 1         Smith, John
Office 2         Smith, John 
Office 3         NULL
Office 4         Smith, John
Office 5         NULL
Office 6         NULL
```

Is there a way to get the results I need?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just move `p.patientID = 111` condition into `ON` clause. In `Where` it effectively changes `outer join` into `inner join`:

```
Select
    Distinct                       --< Substitute for Group By
    m.Name, p.FullName
From MedicalOffice m
Left Join MedicalProcedure p On m.ID = p.officeID AND p.patientID = 111
Where m.ID IN   (1,2,3,4,5,6)
/* Group By m.Name, p.patientID */ --< won't work in this example
Order By m.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
m.ID IN   (1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

This condition will stop null value showup

Comment: But I only need to show the first 6 offices(out of 73).  How do I constrain that otherwise?  Thanks!